# TinyMCE cannot browse for images or files

Tags: tinymce, modx, modx-revolution

I have an issue with TinyMCE (4.3.3) where if you click the image icon, then browse I get a server error within the browsing window that pops up:

`Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.`

The same happens if I click the link icon.

Is this something to do with permissions? If so which file directory I alter?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all files in your tinymce directory can be accessed by the server user.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you have an image inside the folder that has a non-english letter inside the filename?

Answer (score 0):

Probs with entering folders or viewing images are often missing rights. Please check [chmod and chown on your linux-server](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/introduction_to_linux/linux_The_chmod_command.html). Check the attributes of files and folders with an FTP-Client like filezilla, totalcommander or via SSH.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to reinstall TinyMCE or MODX if that didn't work. If you do it right, you won't lose your data. This way all permissions and files are being restored.